# Hyperledger Composer Playground Execution Error

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I'm trying to create my own crypto currency-'WhizCoin' in Hyperledger Composer Playground.
I have created basic model and script files. 2 Participants- Sender and Receiver, and 1 Asset- Coins, and 1 Transaction- DistributeCoins.

/* Model.cto File:- */

```
namespace org.whiz.whizcoin
// ASSETS:-
abstract asset Currency{
  o Double rate default=100.00
  o Double coins
}
asset WhizCoin identified by currencyid extends Currency{
  o String currencyid default = "WhizCoin"
  //--> Member owner
}

// PARTICIPANTS:-
 abstract participant user{
  o String name
  o Integer balance
}
participant Member identified by memberId extends user {
  o String memberId
}

// Transactions:-
transaction distributeCoins {
  --> Member receiver
  o Double amount
  -->Currency wc
}
```

/* logic.js File:- */

```
'use strict';
var NS = 'org.whiz.whizcoin';
/**
 * @param {org.whiz.whizcoin.distributeCoins} distributeCoins - Distribute Coins
 * @transaction
 */
function distributeCoins(distributeCoins) {
  distributeCoins.receiver.balance += distributeCoins.amount;
  distributeCoins.wc.coins -= distributeCoins.amount;

  return getParticipantRegistry('org.whiz.whizcoin.Member')
    .then(function (ParticipantRegistry) {
        return ParticipantRegistry.update(distributeCoins.receiver);
    })
    .then(function() {
        return getAssetRegistry('org.whiz.whizcoin.WhizCoin');
    })
    .then(function (AssetRegistry) {
        return AssetRegistry.update(distributeCoins.whizcoin);
    });
}
```

After submitting the transaction, the error I'm getting is:

`Error: Expected a Resource or Concept.`

I'm really stuck and couldn't find any solution anywhere else. Please help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the section of your logic where you are updating the Asset Registry you are using a variable that doesn't exist in the transaction, whizcoin. In your model file you use the name wc for this. Replacing `AssetRegistry.update(distributeCoins.whizcoin)` with `AssetRegistry.update(distributeCoins.wc)` should fix your issue.

Comment: Oh..A big silly mistake.. Pardon me for that..
 And Thanks!